# Under what circumstances is a fully connected layer similar to PCA?

Tags: neural-networks, pca

I am reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.06626.pdf) on image retrieval where the goal is to train a network that produces highly discriminative descriptors (aka embeddings) for input images. If you are familiar with facial recognition architectures, it is similar in that the network is trained with matching / non-matching pairs and triplet loss.

The paper discusses the use of PCA and whitening on the training set of descriptors as a means of further improving the discriminability (second to last block in image below, fig 1a of paper). This all make sense to me.

[image]

**Where I'm confused** is where they replace PCA/whitening with a trainable fully connected layer with bias. I do understand that PCA+whitening is just the composition of of two linear transformations (ie rotation + (un)squishing in each dimension) and that these are the same as having one linear transformation but:

- How is PCA+whitening equivalent to a learnable fully connected layer? Is there some theorem or paper explaining that training a fully connected layer with triplet loss is somehow statistically equivalent to PCA and whitening?
- Why is there a bias?

Comment: If we ignore the activation function, a fully connected layer on a neural netowrk is nothing but an $m$x$n$ matrix where the data from $m$ neurons gets "summarized" into the output for the $n$ neurons on the following layer. ACP does exactly that in an optimal way, so it's not unreasonable to expect a fully-connected layer in a well-trained neural network to imitate the behaviour of ACP.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @David. I think I'm with you up until "it's not unreasonable to expect". For me it's not obvious that this should be the case. I also imagine it would very much depend on the objective function.